# How do I give table elements a next number?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a jTable where I add elements called customers. Every customer in the list gets a new accountnumber with the code below. numberOfAccounts is a variable and Account() is I think a constructor (I'm new to programming). Both are part of the Account class, which is part of the Customer class, who together form the Bank class.

```
private static int numberOfAccounts = 1000000;

Account() {
    accountNumber = getNextAccountNumber();
}

public static int getNextAccountNumber(){
    return ++numberOfAccounts;
}

private int findValidAccountNumber() {
    int accountNumber = 0;
    do {
        accountNumber = Account.getNextAccountNumber();
    } while(accountExists(accountNumber));      
    return accountNumber;
}

private boolean accountExists(int accountNumber) {
    for(Customer c : customers){
        if(c.getAccount().getAccountNumber() == accountNumber) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The code works fine but let's say I have 5 customers: 1000001 until 1000005. When I delete a customer (eg customer 1000002) from the table and add a new one, I want it to have number 1000002 again. But instead it'll have number 1000006. What am I doing wrong? Sorry if I didn't explain correctly.

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* - Nothing, your `getNextAccountNumber` simply increments the value each time it's called.  The problem you have is knowing when a value can be re-used. The solution isn't generally a simple one.  You'd need to know ALL the values which have been assigned previously (and are in use) and then be able to calculate any gaps in the sequence, so you can find values which could be re-used ...

Comment: You might want to create a list with FIFO behavior, and add the id of deleted customer.
If the next one, you wanna add then go check the list (FIFO). If it is null, it means that there is no "hole" in your list and you should keep increasing `numberOfAccounts`. Otherwise, if your list (FIFO) isn't null, it means that there is a hole and you should take the first element id and add it to your new Customers

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @MadProgrammer I noticed btw that when I restart the app, new customers do get the removed number. How come? I don't really get the `return ++numberOfAccounts;` part.

Comment: When you restart the app, `numberOfAccounts` is reset to `1000000`. `++numberOfAccounts` is doing a pre-increment of the value (`1 + numberOfAccounts`)

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible then to just reset `numberOfAccounts` to 1000000 somewhere in a function?